# Javascript failing on IE works if debugger is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

So, I am in a conundrum with my JS failing after a certain amount of time through the menu navigation. Since it works with the console debugger open, I assumed it was a console.log error, but I have removed those functions.

If you open up this page, http://behrent.com/test/Industry.html, in internet explorer, then use either your arrow keys or the menu headers to scroll many times right or left in a row it will break. It currently works in Chrome and FF. 
It's almost as though the js crashes or something.

Any ideas on what might be occurring? My JS doesn't have any console.log.

On another page using same css and js, but different html it is also producing scary behavior. http://www.behrent.com/test/Services.html. Basically if you go to that site you can navigate through them if you go slowly, but if you go very quick it will then break in the same fashion as the first page.

Just hope I don't have to move to another layout.

Chad

Comment: Does it eventually break in IE even if the console is open?

Comment: Not to my knowledge (2 minutes of rotating), it will just keep rotating as intended.

Comment: I checked your source and saw you didn't have any `console` calls. Are you sure your version isn't cached with the `console` calls still place?

Comment: Unless there is some new way of deleting cache for IE, different than internet options, that I don't know about, I have cleared my cache. Have you tried to navigate all the way through without the console open?

Comment: I don't know man, that's odd. You'll have to get in there and see if you're using something IE pukes on.

Comment: works fine with me on my IE 11.0.9600.17728 ...no console errors or any of that kind

Comment: Roman did you try it without opening the debugger?

Comment: It's behavior is just so bizarre, I have no idea what could be causing the problem. IE you might not use as much ram as Chrome, but goodness you give me headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. IE was expecting background images in the various sections, but I didn't indicate that any existed. IE got confused because it was expecting them as I indicated, but they didn't exist in the css, so it just broke.

Calling not existent sections with js makes things break. The more you know...